# Apple Reachability not showing alert

Tags: ios, swift, reachability

I'm using the Apple's reachability class in my code. Below is the code of the appdelegate

```
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector:"checkForReachability:", name: kReachabilityChangedNotification, object: nil);

    self.reachability = Reachability.reachabilityForInternetConnection();
    self.reachability.startNotifier();
```

and this is checkForReachability

```
func checkForReachability(notification:NSNotification){

    let remoteHostStatus = self.reachability!.currentReachabilityStatus()
    if (remoteHostStatus.rawValue == NotReachable.rawValue) {
        print("NOT REACHABLE")
        let myAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please check your internet connection.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title:"Try again.", style:UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            action in
            self.checkForReachability(notification)
        }
        myAlert.addAction(okAction)
        self.window?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(myAlert, animated:true, completion:nil)
    }


}
```

But it won't pop up the alert when there is no internet(when i turn off the wifi)

Comment: Are you getting the print statement ( Not reachable)  in console?

Answer (score 0):

This might help in the case

i will give best solution, hope its helpful.

```
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

public class ReachabilityCheck {
    class func isConnectionAvailable()->Bool{

        var Status:Bool = false
        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.apple.com/")
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
        request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData
        request.timeoutInterval = 20.0
        request.HTTPMethod = "HEAD"

        var response: NSURLResponse?

        var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: nil) as NSData?

        if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
            if httpResponse.statusCode == 200 {
                Status = true
            }

        }
        else
        {

            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "No Internet Connection", message: "Make sure you are connected to internet.", delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
        }

        return Status
    }
}
```

How to access or call in other classes:

```
 if ReachabilityCheck.isConnectionAvailable() == true {

// write your code here when there is network 

}
```

Comment: Hopefully Yes, let me know if you face any issues